# How to organize big number of header include paths within makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm relatively new to makefiles and I have to write a makefile for a large project to compile the project with the gnu gcc compiler.

The relevant header files for the source files are organized in different subdirectories like this:

```
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\APP\StateManager\Include
D:\MyProject\Tools\
D:\MyProject\Common\Public
D:\MyProject\Function\Modules\FSW\Public
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\Version\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\APP\AC\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\APP\DBDTmanager\Public
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\APP\Diag\Include\
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\APP\FunTTT\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\Basis_SW\Adc\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\Basis_SW\Func2\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\Basis_SW\Stubs\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\Basis_SW\DTC\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\Basis_SW\Generated\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\Basis_SW\Generated_BSM\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\Basis_SW\Functions\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\BistTests\Include
D:\MyProject\SubProject1\Modules\BistTests\Include\WatchDog\Include
D:\MyProject\App\ssw\common\Public
D:\MyProject\Bit\Modules\Timer\Include
```

Any idea how to define the includes in the makefile in a "clearly" and "overseeable" way?

Thx for any suggestions!

Comment: Do those all end up needing to get added to the `gcc` invocation as `-I` flags?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's the same when I would like to compile a source file with gcc command, like: gcc source.c -I[INCLUDE_PATH1] -I[INCLUDE_PATH2] ......

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have any other requirements here and just want a fairly clean way of getting all of those entries into your `CFLAGS` value you could do something like this:

```
PROJDIR := D:\MyProject
SUBPROJDIR := $(PROJDIR)\SubProject1\Modules

CFLAGS += -I$(PROJDIR)\SubProject1\Modules\APP\StateManager\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(PROJDIR)\Tools\
CFLAGS += -I$(PROJDIR)\Common\Public
CFLAGS += -I$(PROJDIR)\Function\Modules\FSW\Public
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\Version\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\APP\AC\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\APP\DBDTmanager\Public
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\APP\Diag\Include\
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\APP\FunTTT\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\Basis_SW\Adc\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\Basis_SW\Func2\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\Basis_SW\Stubs\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\Basis_SW\DTC\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\Basis_SW\Generated\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\Basis_SW\Generated_BSM\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\Basis_SW\Functions\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\BistTests\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(SUBPROJDIR)\BistTests\Include\WatchDog\Include
CFLAGS += -I$(PROJDIR)\App\ssw\common\Public
CFLAGS += -I$(PROJDIR)\Bit\Modules\Timer\Include
```

etc.

Comment: Hi,I have done it exactly like this but I get the message: "gcc.exe error: CFLAGS: No such file or directory" and "+=: No such file or directory" .... any idea? In the documentation of gnu I found the same syntax like shown by you?

Comment: Where did you put those lines? They don't go in the recipe of the target they go in the main body of the makefile (outside of any target).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
INC=-I<header-path-1>  -I<header-path-2> -I<header-path3>
```

PS: they all are seperated by spaces

Comment: OK,but I have about 40 paths :) so on this way it will be a very long line and not very overseeable....

Comment: 1) use INC := ...  so the macro is not re-evaluated each time it is used.  2) place each path on a separate line and end each line, except the last, with ' \'

Comment: If the variable value does not contain any variable references itself I don't believe make re-expands it (and if it does it is likely fairly cheap) but that's probably worth testing at some point.